# How to 'opt-out' an application from GNOME Global Dark Theme?

Tags: gnome, themes, customization, gnome-tweak-tool

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and I have activated the `Global Dark Theme` in the `gnome-tweak-tool`, but there is one problem, I like the Dark Theme in all applications except Nautilus, is there any way of 'opting-out' Nautilus from the Dark Theme without affecting any of the other applications using it? It would also be good if the solution would show how to allow this in most, if not all, applications - so as to be more general and provide a solution not just for Nautilus.

Comment: This would be a great feature. I've noticed a number of text vs background issues in various apps namely the software center.

Comment: @Enigma: Yes, that would be somewhere else useful to use this... Though they are replacing the Ubuntu Software Center with the GNOME Software application in 16.04 so hopefully there won't be an issue there.

Comment: Cheers to that.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly a solution however you could use a different theme that is essentially a dark theme but doesn't affect the application interior like [Numix](https://numixproject.org/).

It's the best of both worlds in my opinion:

[image]
[image]